# Закрыть и тревога - разные вещи?

Tags: обсуждение

Внизу каждого вопроса есть два пункта "закрыть" и "тревога", суть которых одна и та же.

Я за всё время на сайте сотни, если не тысячи вопросов отмечал к закрытию. Но в профиле вижу всего "9 полезных тревог". Получается, что все эти голоса к закрытию - это не то же самое, что и тревоги, и нигде не учитываются и нельзя их историю посмотреть?

Внутри пункты очень похожи, зачем тогда две разные кнопки на одно действие делать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это не совсем так. Где-то функционал тревог и закрытий пересекается, но в целом это разные понятия.

Суть закрытия — "ваш пост не удовлетворяет требованиям качества". Например, плохо сформулирован вопрос, нет конкретики, нет кода, нет внятного описания проблемы и т. п.

Суть тревоги — "ваш пост нарушает правила". Например, пост является спамом, содержит оскорбления и т. п. Также тревоги используются для призыва ромба для разбора сложной ситуации, не вписывающейся в шаблоны.

Ещё одно важное отличие — что и где доступно: закрывать можно только вопросы, тревоги можно отправлять на вопросы, ответы и комментарии.

Теперь о пересечениях.

Первое пересечение возникает, если у пользователя недостаточно репутации для закрытия вопросов. В этом случае он не может проголосовать за закрытие, но может "порекомендовать закрытие" с помощью тревоги. При этом он использует диалог закрытия вопроса, но расходует он тревоги.

После того, как пользователь получает привилегию закрытия и переоткрытия вопросов (3К+), закрытия начинают расходовать голоса за закрытие. И даже когда голоса за закрытие кончатся (их даётся 24 штуки в сутки), воспользоваться тревогами для "рекомендации закрытия", как раньше, не получится.

Второе пересечение — это тревога "низкое качество, следует удалить, не подлежит спасению". Она доступна на вопросах с неположительной оценкой. Если воспользоваться такой тревогой, то вопрос сначала отправится в очередь постов низкого качества и, если будет решено, что качество низкое, далее в очередь на закрытие.

Неочевидное пересечение, которое на самом деле не пересечение — это возможность перейти на диалог закрытия вопроса из диалога отправки тревоги. Это сделано лишь для удобства, чтобы пользователи не заблудились в поисках нужного пункта после "левелапа". Можно заметить, что при переходе в диалог закрытия из диалоги отправки тревоги внизу диалога счётчик доступных тревог меняется на счётчик доступных голосов за закрытие, то есть функционально это разные вещи.

---

История всех ваших голосов за закрытие доступна в вашем профиле на вкладке [*Активность > Голоса > Закрытие*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure).

Comment: То есть, у вас более тысячи тревог на вопросы-оскорбления и вопросы-спамы? Я, честно признать, такие откровенные вопросы со спамом/оскорблениями вижу не чаще, чем раз в неделю.

Comment: @Suvitruf Вот [моя статистика по тревогам](http://i.imgur.com/OZQaaMv.png). В ней нет разбивки по типам тревог для постов и комментариев, но в комментариях много оскорблений и устаревших сообщений, а в постах много VLQ (использую при расчистке мусора, когда кончаются голоса за закрытие). Большая часть жертв найдена через Data.SE, то есть такое число — результат нацеленной чистки сайта, а не случайного натыкания на нарушения. / По сути, Маршала можно получить двумя способами: нацеленно искать нарушения всеми доступными средствами (Discord, PashaPash), не зарабатывать репу (Normal Human).

Comment: @Suvitruf Голоса за закрытие, переоткрытие, удаление и восстановление ни в каких глобальных счётчиках не отображаются, ни на какие значки не влияют. Значки за закрытие-переоткрытие даются, только если голос дан в очередях проверок. А то я бы тоже не был прочь покрасоваться своими счётчиками голосов, у меня их 1500 за закрытие, 300 за удаление и так далее. :)